# jQuery - if two classes - get the first one

Tags: jquery

Example:

Here we have `<p class="tab1 current"></p>`

How can I get only the first class?

`var GetFirstClass = $('p').attr('class').filter(':first');` ??

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use JavaScript's [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
$('p').attr('class').split(' ')[0]
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/bkmXm/)

Comment: @Pete: To be fair, @chrisdpratt said it first. Damn you, unintelligible Captcha! :)

Comment: this wont work if there are no classes, might want to store p.attr('class') and check it before

Answer (score 6):

```
$('p').attr('class').split(' ')[0]
```

Comment: +1 for getting the same answer as me just before me, but missing out on the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` the string based on the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div class="a b"/>').attr('class').split(' ')[0]
```